# mysql error in my page

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need help with an issue I am having connecting to my database and getting what I want. I have programmed in php before and never ran into this problem. I am getting this error message.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'character WHERE username = David' at line 1

This is my code.

```
    <?php
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","thespianassistant");
        $username = $_GET['username'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `character` WHERE `username` = $username";
        $data = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    ?>
```

Comment: you need to quote strings '' - aside from this, you system is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and you're using a deprecated function set - you should be using either PDO or mysqli

Comment: Do you mean quote the $username?

Comment: Obligatory Suggestion, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: And `character` is reserved by mysql. You will need backticks.

Comment: Also, thank you for the tip about sql injection. I will edit it to be mysqli

Comment: **Pro Tip** when debugging SQL queries, the first thing you should do is `echo` the query to see exactly what's being sent to the server. Often your error will be immediately apparent.

Comment: Should I change character to something else then?

Comment: Also, thank you Kryten for the helpful tip.

Comment: backtick the word character: \`character\`

Comment: It's good practice to backtick (in MySQL) all field and table names, just in case you accidentally use a reserved keyword as a name. It's faster to just do them all than to look at each one and try to determine if it's some obscure keyword you never heard of. Other databases use something other than backticks.

Comment: @Trent what specific strings are you referring too? Are you referring to the $username variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a port of your code using PDO perhaps it will be of interest, don't use the old mysql_* functions.

```
<?php
//connect to database using PDO
try{
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=thespianassistant', 'root', 'you_should_set_a_password');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    //Query the db & fetch result
    $sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM `character` 
            WHERE username = :username";

    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(':username' => $_GET['username']));

    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}catch(PDOException $e){
    die($e->getMessage());
}

//do something with result
if(!empty($result)){
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($result, true).'</pre>';
}else{
    //no character found
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Also, I have a password. Haha, I just didn't want to share it. Thanks again @LozCherone

Comment: np, its possible to install with no pw, that's why I said, though take note of the PDO suggestion, I generally like most others wont help OP's if there using `mysql_*` your just get the spammy-for-good-reason comments telling to to move to PDO or mysqli. good luck